# CSS navigation bar centered in middle of page

Tags: html, css

I have a pure css navigation bar on my website that has this code...

```
.nav {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #3399ff;
    text-align: center;
}
.item {
    float: left;
    display: inline;
}
.item a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
}
.item a:hover {
    background-color: #a300cc;
    color: white;
}
```

And the HTML...

```
<ul class="nav" style="text-align:center">
    <li class="item"><u><a href="http://www.coding-kids.net/"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a></u></li>
    <li class="item"><u><a href="http://ask.coding-kids.net/"><i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i> Ask Codey</a></u></li>
    <li class="item"><u><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#comingSoon"><i class="fa fa-puzzle-piece"></i> Extras</a></u></li>
</ul>
```

And I am trying to make it centered in the middle of the page. I have tried wrapping it in a `div` and styling it with `text-align:center;`, but the navigation bar does not move, only the text inside it. How do I make it be in the middle of the page?

Comment: margin: 0 auto; might help :)

Comment: accept my comment if the solution is working for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `flex`

This is the code:

```
<ul class="nav" style="display:flex; justify-content:center">
    <li class="item"><u><a href="http://www.coding-kids.net/"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a></u></li>
    <li class="item"><u><a href="http://ask.coding-kids.net/"><i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i> Ask Codey</a></u></li>
    <li class="item"><u><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#comingSoon"><i class="fa fa-puzzle-piece"></i> Extras</a></u></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:
For nav class use some fixed with and apply margin:0 auto to it, this will make it center of the page.

```
.nav {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: #3399ff;
    width:500px;
    margin:0 auto;
    }
```

Comment: The only problem with this as it does not fully center in the page - you have to keep the width as 500px. Can you help?

Comment: Hi Daniel,, The width here is used for only illustration purpose,,you have to change the width according to your needs...in most of cases the nav width  would be same as the page width of your website.

Comment: I have tried that but as soon as I change it from 500px it goes back to the left. I have now found a solution, though, using `flex`.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

> CSS

```
.nav {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #3399ff;
  text-align: center;
}
.item {
  display: inline;
}
.item a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
}
.item a:hover {
  background-color: #a300cc;
  color: white;
}
```

> HTML

```
<ul class="nav" style="text-align:center">
    <li class="item"><u><a href="http://www.coding-kids.net/"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a></u></li>
    <li class="item"><u><a href="http://ask.coding-kids.net/"><i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i> Ask Codey</a></u></li>
    <li class="item"><u><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#comingSoon"><i class="fa fa-puzzle-piece"></i> Extras</a></u></li>
</ul>
```

Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/330LxuL3/

Solved by removing the `float` by `.item` in you CSS

Comment: For some reason, this answer stacks the menu items on top of each other. @satya gave an answer that works, though.

Answer (score -1):

Remove `float: left;` in `.item` css. New Css is

```
.nav {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #3399ff;
  text-align: center;
}
.item {
  display: inline;
}
.item a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
}
.item a:hover {
  background-color: #a300cc;
  color: white;
}
```